# Class name not defined even after stating it

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python GUI programming and went through this tutorial stating Tkinter uses

I tried the following code

```
import Tkinter

class  simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
     def __init__(self,parent):
           Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
           self.parent=parent
           self.initialize()

  def initialize(self):
        pass
  if  __name__=="__main__":
        app=simpleapp_tk(None)
        app.title('my application')
        app.mainloop()
```

I expected a blank window but instead got this

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vedev/Desktop/python/app1.py", line 3, in <module>
    class  simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
  File "C:/Users/vedev/Desktop/python/app1.py", line 12, in simpleapp_tk
app=simpleapp_tk(None)
NameError: name 'simpleapp_tk' is not defined
```

How do i debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with your indentation. Just don't indent

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

In your current code the if statement is executed while `simpleapp_tk` is being defined, thus `name 'simpleapp_tk' is not defined`.

See [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation)

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

Comment: Yeah..got it now.! thanx for assistance @tynn

Answer (score 0):

The whole if-statement is in the class. It will work if you move it outside.

The problem is that this way, the if-statement is executed as soon as the class is being defined, but during the class definition, you can't access it yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the indentation part. You need to follow a single indentation level for the entire block, in this case the **class simpleapp_tk**. Here is the above code that works perfectly for me:

```
import Tkinter

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```